# boost::shared_ptr, access to a variable after inheritance?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, boost, shared-ptr

I use MonkSVG library:

[goal file](https://github.com/micahpearlman/MonkSVG/blob/4cfa81927b3bdbe7369f5dfab690b8e2595f5d05/src/mkSVG.h)

A class object is defined as:

```
//mkSVG.h

namespace MonkSVG {
        using namespace std;

    class SVG;

        class ISVGHandler {
        public:

                typedef boost::shared_ptr<ISVGHandler> SmartPtr;

                ...

                ISVGHandler::SmartPtr                _handler;

        ...
```

Then the author of this library defines [another class](https://github.com/micahpearlman/MonkSVG/blob/4cfa81927b3bdbe7369f5dfab690b8e2595f5d05/src/openvg/mkOpenVG_SVG.h?source=cc):

```
class OpenVG_SVGHandler : public ISVGHandler
```

And it is possible to access to variables of `ISVGHandler` via `_handler` from `SVG`.

I inherited my 2 own classes: the first one from `ISVGHandler` and the second one is from `SVG`, and the first one has its own variables, but I can't get access to them directly. The only solution I found is to create a setter-getter methods, but even so I need to define them in both root class and the last inherited class.

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: `boost::dynamic_pointer_cast` comes to mind, but if you really need that, you should rethink your design. If you need an instance of your derived classes, then explicitly say so, instead of (possibly dangerous) casting around.

Comment: I assume you must use the factory generator to construct the handler, static ISVGHandler::SmartPtr OpenVG_ISVGHandler::create()? Is there a risk of multiple different types of SVG getting mixed up with multiple different types of SVGHandler, or will the program always use exactly one type (OpenVG)?

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to define your own handler using ISVGHandler, but to add and use new functions, you are making a derived SVG as well.  Your SVG has to have your handler to work, so you can either make them both at the same time, or have initialize check it for you just to be sure.

```
#define MAKE_YOUR_OWN_HANDLER

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

// darned compiler not up to date
#define nullptr NULL

class ISVGHandler {
protected:
    ISVGHandler(){} // interface, must be derived
public:
    virtual ~ISVGHandler(){}

    typedef boost::shared_ptr<ISVGHandler> SmartPtr;
    void onPathBegin() {std::cout << "base onPathBegin" << std::endl;}
    void onPathEnd() {std::cout << "base onPathEnd" << std::endl;}
};

class OpenVG_SVGHandler : public ISVGHandler {
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<OpenVG_SVGHandler> SmartPtr;
    static ISVGHandler::SmartPtr create() {
        return boost::make_shared<OpenVG_SVGHandler>();
    }

    void draw() {std::cout << "openvg draw" << std::endl;}
    void optimize() {std::cout << "openvg optimize" << std::endl;}
};

class WrongHandler : public ISVGHandler {
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<OpenVG_SVGHandler> SmartPtr;
    static ISVGHandler::SmartPtr create() {
        return boost::make_shared<WrongHandler>();
    }

    void draw() {std::cout << "openvg draw" << std::endl;}
    void optimize() {std::cout << "openvg optimize" << std::endl;}
};

class SVG {
public:
    virtual ~SVG(){}

    bool initialize(ISVGHandler::SmartPtr handler) {
        _handler = handler; 
        std::cout << "base init" << std::endl; 
        return true;}

    void onPathBegin() {_handler->onPathBegin();}
    void onPathEnd()   {_handler->onPathEnd();}
private:
    ISVGHandler::SmartPtr _handler;
};

class OpenVG_SVG : public SVG {
private:
    OpenVG_SVGHandler * m_pOpenVG_Handler;

public:
#ifdef MAKE_YOUR_OWN_HANDLER
    OpenVG_SVG(){
        // use factory to make correct handler
        ISVGHandler::SmartPtr spBaseHandler (OpenVG_SVGHandler::create());

        // store known handler type for this class to use
        m_pOpenVG_Handler = reinterpret_cast<OpenVG_SVGHandler*>(spBaseHandler.get());

        // initialize the SVG base class
        initialize(spBaseHandler);
    }
#else
    OpenVG_SVG() : m_pOpenVG_Handler(nullptr) {}

    bool initialize(ISVGHandler::SmartPtr handler){
        try {
            m_pOpenVG_Handler = dynamic_cast<OpenVG_SVGHandler*>(handler.get());
            if (m_pOpenVG_Handler){
                std::cout << "openvg svg init" << std::endl;
                return SVG::initialize(handler);
            } else {
                std::cout << "wrong handler" << std::endl;
            }
        } catch (std::exception &e){
            std::cout << "wrong handler: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
        return false;
    }
#endif

    // write functions that are OpenVG specific in this class, using m_pOpenVG_Handler
    void draw() { m_pOpenVG_Handler->draw(); } // I'd check for null but that's not relevant to the question
    void optimize() {m_pOpenVG_Handler->optimize(); }

    // let the virtual functions handle all the other behavior.
};

int test_svg()
{
    OpenVG_SVG ovg;
#ifndef MAKE_YOUR_OWN_HANDLER
    ovg.initialize(OpenVG_SVGHandler::create());
#endif
    ovg.draw();
    ovg.onPathBegin();
    ovg.onPathEnd();
    ovg.optimize();

#ifndef MAKE_YOUR_OWN_HANDLER
    std::cout << "attempting to initialize with wrong handler:" << std::endl;
    OpenVG_SVG bad;
    if (bad.initialize(WrongHandler::create())){
        bad.draw();
    }
#endif
    return 0;
}
```